# How can I check MySQL engine type for a specific table?

Tags: mysql, innodb, myisam

My MySQL database contains several tables using different storage engines
(specifically myisam and innodb).  How can I find out which tables are
using which engine?

Answer (score 607, accepted):

```
SHOW TABLE STATUS WHERE Name = 'xxx'
```

This will give you (among other things) an `Engine` column, which is what you want.

Comment: If my table is damaged, it's simply shows Engine=NULL and has a "Comment" telling me to repair the table.  However, before I know how to repair the table, I'm guessing I need to know the engine (I haven't gotten that far to be honest.)  Therefore, @Jocker's comment below was much more helpful to me.

Comment: @Greg, Should we use this or Jocker's solution?

Comment: @Pacerier - Both work fine. The difference is that this solution gives the info for one table, while Jocker's solution shows the engine type for all tables in a database (while being a bit more readable as well).

Comment: @Greg, Btw why doesn't engine info show up when we do `show full columns from t1`?

Answer (score 298):

To show a list of all the tables in a database and their engines, use this SQL query:

```
SELECT TABLE_NAME,
       ENGINE
FROM   information_schema.TABLES
WHERE  TABLE_SCHEMA = 'dbname';
```

Replace `dbname` with your database name.

Comment: This is great b/c it filters out everything but tablename and engine.

Comment: To get engine of specific table, you may use:

`SELECT ENGINE
FROM   information_schema.TABLES
WHERE  
    TABLE_SCHEMA = '<database_name>'
    AND TABLE_NAME = '<table_name>'`

Comment: This gives me an empty set on MySQL 5.6.37.

Comment: This is a better answer because it's true SQL, so I can do things like `COUNT(*)` and `GROUP BY`.

Answer (score 59):

```
SHOW CREATE TABLE <tablename>;
```

Less parseable but more readable than `SHOW TABLE STATUS`.

Answer (score 54):

Or just run this:

```
show table status;
```

This will list all tables and related details on your database.

Comment: @NikolaiSamteladze, Do have you tables in the selected db?

Comment: the best and easiest way!

Answer (score 21):

Bit of a tweak to Jocker's response (I would post as a comment, but I don't have enough karma yet):

```
SELECT TABLE_NAME, ENGINE
  FROM information_schema.TABLES
 WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'database' AND ENGINE IS NOT NULL;
```

This excludes MySQL views from the list, which don't have an engine.

Answer (score 12):

```
SHOW CREATE TABLE <tablename>\G
```

will format it much nicer compared to the output of

```
SHOW CREATE TABLE <tablename>;
```

The `\G` trick is also useful to remember for many other queries/commands.

Comment: \G hack is only under cli mysql

Comment: Great solution thanks

Answer (score 11):

> show table status from database_name;

It will list all tables from the mentioned database.
**Example output**

[image: sample output of mysql db]

> show table status where name=your_desired_table_name;

It will show the storage engine used by the mentioned table.

Answer (score 8):

```
mysqlshow -i <database_name>
```

will show the info for all tables of a specific database.

```
mysqlshow -i <database_name> <table_name>
```

will do so just for a specific table.

Answer (score 5):

If you're using [MySQL Workbench](https://www.mysql.com/products/workbench/), right-click a table and select `alter table`.

In that window you can see your table Engine and also change it.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Yet another way, perhaps the shortest to get status of a single or matched set of tables:

```
SHOW TABLE STATUS LIKE 'table';
```

You can then use LIKE operators for example:

```
SHOW TABLE STATUS LIKE 'field_data_%';
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are a linux user:

To show the engines for all tables for all databases on a mysql server, without tables `information_schema`, `mysql`, `performance_schema`:

```
less < <({ for i in $(mysql -e "show databases;" | cat | grep -v -e Database-e information_schema -e mysql -e performance_schema); do echo "--------------------$i--------------------";  mysql -e "use $i; show table status;"; done } | column -t)
```

You might love this, if you are on linux, at least.

Will open all info for all tables in `less`, press `-S` to chop overly long lines.

Example output:

```
--------------------information_schema--------------------
Name                                                        Engine              Version  Row_format  Rows   Avg_row_length  Data_length  Max_data_length     Index_length  Data_free  Auto_increment  Create_time  Update_time  Check_time  C
CHARACTER_SETS                                              MEMORY              10       Fixed       NULL   384             0            16434816            0             0          NULL            2015-07-13   15:48:45     NULL        N
COLLATIONS                                                  MEMORY              10       Fixed       NULL   231             0            16704765            0             0          NULL            2015-07-13   15:48:45     NULL        N
COLLATION_CHARACTER_SET_APPLICABILITY                       MEMORY              10       Fixed       NULL   195             0            16357770            0             0          NULL            2015-07-13   15:48:45     NULL        N
COLUMNS                                                     MyISAM              10       Dynamic     NULL   0               0            281474976710655     1024          0          NULL            2015-07-13   15:48:45     2015-07-13  1
COLUMN_PRIVILEGES                                           MEMORY              10       Fixed       NULL   2565            0            16757145            0             0          NULL            2015-07-13   15:48:45     NULL        N
ENGINES                                                     MEMORY              10       Fixed       NULL   490             0            16574250            0             0          NULL            2015-07-13   15:48:45     NULL        N
EVENTS                                                      MyISAM              10       Dynamic     NULL   0               0            281474976710655     1024          0          NULL            2015-07-13   15:48:45     2015-07-13  1
FILES                                                       MEMORY              10       Fixed       NULL   2677            0            16758020            0             0          NULL            2015-07-13   15:48:45     NULL        N
GLOBAL_STATUS                                               MEMORY              10       Fixed       NULL   3268            0            16755036            0             0          NULL            2015-07-13   15:48:45     NULL        N
GLOBAL_VARIABLES                                            MEMORY              10       Fixed       NULL   3268            0            16755036            0             0          NULL            2015-07-13   15:48:45     NULL        N
KEY_COLUMN_USAGE                                            MEMORY              10       Fixed       NULL   4637            0            16762755            0 

.
.
.
```

Answer (score 0):

go to information_schema database there you will find 'tables' table then select it;

Mysql>use information_schema;
Mysql> select table_name,engine from  tables;

Answer (score 0):

If you are a **GUI** guy and just want to find it in **PhpMyAdmin**, than pick the table of your choice and head over the `Operations` tab >> `Table options` >> `Storage Engine`.
You can even change it from there using the drop-down options list.

PS: This guide is based on version 4.8 of PhpMyAdmin. Can't guarantee the same path for very older versions.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from examples showed in previous entries, you can also get that from information_schema db with standard query as follows :

```
use information_schema;

select NAME from INNODB_TABLES where NAME like "db_name%";
```