# How to select the MySQL's engine name of some table by sql query?

Tags: sql, mysql, innodb, myisam

How to select the MySQL's engine name of some table. MyISAM or InnoDB.
Can we do it by a simple sql query?

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/213543/how-can-i-check-mysql-engine-type-for-a-specific-table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
SHOW TABLE STATUS FROM db_name
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the INFOMATION_SCHEMA database:

```
SELECT ENGINE FROM TABLES WHERE TABLE_NAME LIKE 'words';
```