# How do I find if my a table is MyISAM or Innodb

Tags: mysql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I check MySQL engine type for a specific table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/213543/how-can-i-check-mysql-engine-type-for-a-specific-table)

Assuming that users is a table following command does not reveal if users table is MyISAM or Innodb.

```
desc users;
```

How do I find what is the type of users table?

Comment: Got it. show create table users does it. May be someone has a better solution.

Answer (score 65):

You can use [`SHOW TABLE STATUS`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/show-table-status.html) to see table information.

```
SHOW TABLE STATUS WHERE `Name` = 'my_table';
```

Simply check the value of the `Engine` column in the returned dataset to know which engine the table is using.

Answer (score 27):

```
SELECT ENGINE
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES 

WHERE TABLE_NAME='your_table_name'
AND   TABLE_SCHEMA='your_database_name';
-- or use TABLE_SCHEMA=DATABASE() if you have a default one.
```

Answer (score 12):

You can use `SHOW CREATE TABLE` and look for the `ENGINE` part in the response.

```
SHOW CREATE TABLE users;
```

Example:

```
CREATE TABLE innodb_table (id int, value int) ENGINE=INNODB;
CREATE TABLE myisam_table (id int, value int) ENGINE=MYISAM;
CREATE TABLE default_table (id int, value int);
```

Result for `innodb_table`:

```
SHOW CREATE TABLE innodb_table;
+--------------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Table        | Create Table                                                                                                                     |
+--------------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| innodb_table | CREATE TABLE `innodb_table` (
  `id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `value` int(11) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 |
+--------------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Result for `myisam_table`:

```
SHOW CREATE TABLE myisam_table;
+--------------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Table        | Create Table                                                                                                                     |
+--------------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| myisam_table | CREATE TABLE `myisam_table` (
  `id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `value` int(11) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 |
+--------------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Result for `default_table`:

```
SHOW CREATE TABLE default_table;
+---------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Table         | Create Table                                                                                                                      |
+---------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| default_table | CREATE TABLE `default_table` (
  `id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `value` int(11) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 |
+---------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: -1: This is a uselessly costly way of knowing the storage engine.

Comment: @Andrew: What does it cost? ... Technically your answer is probably better, but the response of `SHOW CREATE TABLE` is not only easier to read (in my opinion) but also shorter to type.

Comment: +1. This is probably the most common and easy to remember way to check the storage engine, even if slightly 'noisy.'

Comment: `SHOW CREATE TABLE` requires the database to fetch information about all indexes, columns and triggers currently defined on that table. This is not the case with `SHOW TABLE STATUS`.

Comment: @Andrew - Who gives a toss about the cost of a one-time check on the storage engine?

Comment: @Hammerite: I think Andrew was saying this is not the right answer. Which it's not.

Comment: @AndrewMoore "costly" may be relative, and may depend on other factors. On my DB, "show table status" took 4.75 sec, "show create table" took 0.85 sec. ("select engine from information_schema.tables" took 0.0 sec)