# How do I know if a mysql table is using myISAM or InnoDB Engine?

Tags: mysql, innodb, myisam, storage-engines

In MySQL, there is no way to specify a storage engine for a certain database, only for single tables.  However, you can specify a storage engine to be used during one session with:

```
SET storage_engine=InnoDB;
```

So you don't have to specify it for each table.

**How do I confirm, if indeed all the tables are using InnoDB?**

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I check MySQL engine type for a specific table?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/213543/how-can-i-check-mysql-engine-type-for-a-specific-table)

Answer (score 156, accepted):

If you use SHOW CREATE TABLE, you have to parse the engine out of the query.

Selecting from the INFORMATION_SCHEMA database is poor practice, as the devs reserve the right to change its schema at any time (though it is unlikely).

The correct query to use is **[SHOW TABLE STATUS](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/show-table-status.html)** - you can get information on all the tables in a database:

```
SHOW TABLE STATUS FROM `database`;
```

Or for a specific table:

```
SHOW TABLE STATUS FROM `database` LIKE 'tablename';
```

One of the columns you will get back is Engine.

Comment: +1, except you always have permission to see the information schema for the objects you have permission to.

Comment: @Konerak Ah, true enough - I'll correct the answer.  As an aside, I have seen some _bugs_ where selecting from information_schema did not work in cases where people had the correct permissions.

Answer (score 19):

```
SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'db name' AND ENGINE != 'InnoDB'
```

Comment: Only caveat is data in INFORMATION_SCHEMA is cached, so best to use [FLUSH TABLES](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/flush.html) prior to the statement you provided

Comment: It helps me to count the no of InnoDB tables in DB.

Answer (score 5):

`show create table <table>` should do the trick.