# How to check if MySQL table is UTF-8 and has storageEngine InnoDB?

Tags: mysql, utf-8, innodb, storage-engines

Googling around just finds instructions for changing from one format to another, but I can't seem to find how exactly to make sure which of these I have first.

How can I:

1. Check what character encoding a table has?
2. Check what storage engine a table uses?
3. Check if all tables are certain encoding?
4. Check if all tables have a certain storage engine?

Comment: This may be useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4515490/how-do-i-know-if-a-mysql-table-is-using-myisam-or-innodb-engine/4515794#4515794

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You can use information_schema in order to know the engine of each table.

```
select table_name,engine 
from information_schema.tables
where table_schema = 'your_database'
```

For the encoding you can use

```
show create table table_name
```

or, even better

```
select 
c.character_set_name 
from information_schema.tables as t,
     information_schema.collation_character_set_applicability as c
where c.collation_name = t.table_collation
and t.table_schema = "your_db"
and t.table_name = "table_name";
```

Comment: It makes sense, but are you sure that is the syntax?  I get this error: Unknown column 'users' in 'field list'

Comment: Hi. Yes, I'm sure. It's a simple query on the information_schema that works with mysql >= 5.0. What are you talking about, my first or second query?

Comment: I was trying the first query.  But I'll keep hacking around with it

Comment: Oh I know what I was doing wrong..I was plugging in the actual table name in the select clause of the first query lol....ok all works super nicely - thank you!

Comment: Glad I could help you. Bye :)