# mysql dump big file encoding issue

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, dump

tried to execute dump file in mysql as i usually do with the big files:

```
mysql -u root -p database_name < mysql_dump.sql
```

and exactly after this i receive error

```
ERROR at line 1: Unknown command '\�'.
```

opening file to see what is there...
in preview mode looks ok
but when i open it in edit mode i see hieroglyphs like
[image]

seems to me problem in locale encoding or so, im not very good in linux, what should i do to import the dump step by step pls.

Comment: is UTF-8 Enabled ?

Comment: idk how to test, as i said im not very good in linux

Comment: Is it mostly English or does it have other languages ?

Comment: terminal seems to me support UTF-8
jack@Lenovo-ubuntu:~/Downloads$ $LANG
> en_US.UTF-8: command not found
jack@Lenovo-ubuntu:~/Downloads$ echo -e '\xe2\x82\xac' 
> €

there inside dump could be russian and other languages

Comment: what about the Database you are trying to export ? Is it UTF-8, For info refer to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6103595/how-to-check-if-mysql-table-is-utf-8-and-has-storageengine-innodb

Comment: im trying to import dump file into the newly created database with the UTF8 collation

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/120965/discussion-between-unknowndeveloper-and-eugene).