# What does NULL in the `engine` column of SHOW TABLE STATUS in a MySQL Database mean?

Tags: mysql, innodb

The output of `show table status` for my MySQL database has many rows in the engine column with values of InnoDB and many rows with values of NULL.

Why are some rows NULL? Shouldn't that be impossible? It is a very old database, perhaps the engine was not properly set when InnoDB was released?

Is this a problem I should try to fix?

Related:
[How do I know if a mysql table is using myISAM or InnoDB Engine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4515490/how-do-i-know-if-a-mysql-table-is-using-myisam-or-innodb-engine)

Comment: Can we see the output result of `show table status`?

Comment: Thank you for your comment...I went back to look at the table again to see what I could post and noticed that it was not tables but VIEWS that were null, the reason must be that....

Answer (score 2):

The `show table status` command shows both tables and views. The views are marked null across the engine column and across most other columns.