# Cascade delete not working on php Laravel 8.21.0

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, database-design, laravel-8

[image]

I am using  PHP laravel 8.21.0
I have 3 tables. student, grade, and test.
When I delete student data, I want all associated grade data to be deleted.
Similarly, when I delete test data, I want the associated grade data to be deleted.

I tried using cascade delete, which does not seem to work.
Am I doing something wrong? Any better way to make this work?
Does anyone have a better idea to structure this relationship...

Grade table Schema:

```
 public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('grades', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id('id')->unique();
            $table->foreignId('test_id')->constrained()->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->foreignId('student_id')->constrained()->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->date('testDate');
            $table->integer('testCount');
            $table->integer('vocabScore');
            $table->integer('readingScore');
            $table->integer('listeningScore');
            $table->integer('rawTotal');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

Comment: What is your table engine? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24897300/laravel-foreign-key-ondeletecascade-not-working

Comment: My table engine is set to null.     'engine' => null
I am using mysql database and currently running on localhost

Comment: Check your table engin pls. It wouldn't be null. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4515490/how-do-i-know-if-a-mysql-table-is-using-myisam-or-innodb-engine

Comment: I tested your migration code and it works fine to me. You can try to rollback the migration and migrate the table again.

Comment: try to make the forign key like this :         $table->foreign('test_id')->references('id')->on('tests')->onDelete('cascade');
then you should work in innodb database engine  like this :- $table->engine = 'InnoDB';

Comment: @MohamedAhmed I think that method is deprecated in laravel 8.21.0 It does not work

Comment: exit in laravel 8 see this docx :- https://laravel.com/docs/master/migrations#database-connection-table-options