# mysql full text search error

Tags: mysql, full-text-search, mysql-error-1214

I try to add full text search to an existing table. When I tried:

```
alter table tweets add fulltext index(tags);
```

I got the error:

```
ERROR 1214 (HY000): The used table type doesn't support FULLTEXT indexes
```

what is the problem? How can I know what table type it is?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is how you check the table type:

```
SELECT table_schema,engine FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_name='tweet';
```

Only `MyISAM` supports `FULLTEXT Indexes`.

You may also want to preempt the stopword list.

[Click Here for the Stop Words that `FullText Indexing` Would Normally Ignore.](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/fulltext-stopwords.html)

You can override this as Follows:

1) Create a text file in `/var/lib/mysql` like this

```
echo "a" > /var/lib/mysql/stopwords.txt<BR>
echo "an" >> /var/lib/mysql/stopwords.txt<BR>
echo "the" >> /var/lib/mysql/stopwords.txt<BR>
```

2) Add this to `/etc/my.cnf`

```
ft_stopword_file=/var/lib/mysql/stopwords.txt<BR>
ft_min_word_len=2
```

3) service mysql restart

Here is something else to consider:

You may not want to convert the table 'tweets' to `MyISAM`.

1) If the `InnoDB` table 'tweets' contains `CONSTRAINT(s)`.

2) If the `InnoDB` table 'tweets' is the parent of other `InnoDB` tables with Foreign Key Constraints back to 'tweets'.

3) You cannot afford to have table-level locking of the 'tweets' table.

Remember, each `INSERT` into the 'tweets' table will trigger a table-level lock if it were a `MyISAM` table. Since it currently an `InnoDB` table (which does row-level locking), the 'tweets' table can be `INSERTed` into very quickly.

You many want to create a separate `MyISAM` table, called `tweets_tags`, with the same Primary Key of the 'tweets' table along with a `TEXT` column called 'tags' the same as in the 'tweets' table.

Next, do an initial load of tweets_tags like this:

```
INSERT INTO tweets_tags (id,tags) SELECT id,tags FROM tweets;
```

Then, periodically (every night or every 6 hours), load new tweets into tweets_tags like this :

```
INSERT INTO tweets_tags (id,tags) SELECT id,tags FROM tweets WHERE id > (SELECT max(id) FROM tweets_tags);
```

Comment: wow~~~ This is amazing.., more than I expected originally.... Thanks dude. You are so great~~

Answer (score 10):

If you want to use full text indexing you need to make sure your table's underlying engine is MyISAM.  You can change this using `ALTER TABLE tweets ENGINE = MYISAM;`

Comment: by the way, how can I know its current table type?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/213543/how-can-i-check-mysql-engine-type-for-a-specific-table