# How to find the MySQL engine of a table

Tags: mysql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I check MySQL engine type for a specific table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/213543/how-can-i-check-mysql-engine-type-for-a-specific-table)

What is the query to get the table engine other than `show create table table_name` and `show  status`?

Comment: Have a look at the answer with ~27 rep.

Answer (score 0):

For one table:

```
SELECT table_name,engine FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES 
WHERE table_name='table_name';
```

For all the tables in the schema:

```
SELECT table_name,engine FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES 
WHERE table_schema='schema_name';
```

When logged in as the same schema:

```
SELECT table_name,engine FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES 
WHERE table_schema=DATABASE();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SHOW TABLE STATUS [{FROM | IN} db_name]
    [LIKE 'pattern' | WHERE expr]
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/show-table-status.html