# Nested MySQL select error

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to make the following transaction work, but the I get a mysql error near SELECT. I've double-checked that all column names are correct.

**Error message**

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'INSERT INTO articles (catid,content,title,keywords,isactive) (SELEC' at line 2

**SQL**

```
START TRANSACTION; 
INSERT INTO articles (catid,content,title,keywords,isactive) 
(SELECT 1, pendingarticles.content, pendingarticles.title, 
pendingarticles.keywords, 1 
FROM pendingarticles 
WHERE pendingarticles.id=1);
DELETE FROM pendingarticles WHERE id=1; 
COMMIT;
```

**UPDATE**

The code itself works. Both the INSERT INTO - SELECT part, and the DELETE part. Something's wrong with the transaction. Perhaps `;`? Or my db server can't do transactions?

Comment: What does the error say ?

Comment: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'INSERT INTO articles (catid,content,title,keywords,isactive) (SELEC' at line 2

Comment: Not sure if this will make a difference, but I don't think the `SELECT` should be in brackets.

Comment: Me neither, I added it trying to fix the problem.

Comment: Did you forget `VALUES`, `INSERT INTO table (....) VALUES (...);`  ?

Comment: VALUES are only needed for a value list, in this case I'm selecting something form another table.

Comment: (Of course I checked the code both ways, with and without `VALUES`)

Comment: Did you try to run only the select statement? does it work?

Comment: Good idea. I'll check it soon

Comment: if you run this command `SHOW CREATE TABLE tableName` you can see what ENIGNE is used for the tables. the engine has to support transactions.

Comment: I can't run MySQL commands, only queries.

Comment: would be useful to know the engine `SELECT TABLE_NAME, ENGINE FROM information_schema.TABLES where TABLE_SCHEMA = 'dbname'`  [How can I check MySQL engine type for a specific table?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/213543/how-can-i-check-mysql-engine-type-for-a-specific-table)

Comment: It's MyISAM (phpmyadmin showed me)

Comment: My lolcat says: "MyIZAM can't into tranzactionz"

Comment: Should I just `ALTER TABLE articles ENGINE=InnoDB`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MyISAM Engine does not support transactions. [MyIsam engine transaction support](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8036005/myisam-engine-transaction-support)

To support transactions you have to change the engine f.e. to InnoDB. [Setting the Storage Engine](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/storage-engine-setting.html)

Comment: And here's the winner for me! somebody that can see past his nose before answering :D

Comment: It turns out that the server does not support innoDB, so I must continue working without this feature. Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 0):

you want:

```
INSERT INTO articles (catid,content,title,keywords,isactive)  
SELECT 1,pendingarticles.content,pendingarticles.title,  
        pendingarticles.keywords,1  
FROM pendingarticles  
WHERE pendingarticles.id=1;  
DELETE FROM pendingarticles WHERE id=1;
```

The extra set of parenthesis you provided is not necessary.

Answer (score -1):

I believe that the parentheses around the Select are not necessary.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/insert.html

```
START TRANSACTION; 
INSERT INTO articles (catid,content,title,keywords,isactive) 
SELECT 1, pendingarticles.content, pendingarticles.title, 
pendingarticles.keywords, 1 
FROM pendingarticles 
WHERE pendingarticles.id=1;
DELETE FROM pendingarticles WHERE id=1; 
COMMIT;
```

Comment: i think you mean parenthesis ()  these are brackets []

Comment: @Dukeling and yet the image that is there says brackets are are these things []

Comment: @Woot4Moo "Parentheses ... (also called simply brackets ...". Bottom line is - you may not call them brackets, but that doesn't stop other people from being correct while calling them brackets.