# MySQL error that I can't solve

Tags: php, mysql, utf-8, error-handling, utf

Upon installing LiteCart, an open-source shopping cart script, I get this error:

Checking MySQL version...

> Fatal error: 1115 - Unknown character set: 'utf8';' set names 'utf8';

in **/storage/h3/487/604487/public_html/shop/includes/library/lib_database.inc.php on line 220**

Can someone help me understand it and solve it?

In the configuration of `LiteCart`. I've tried many types of `UTF8` collations. Now using `utf8_swedish_ci` and my webhosting database is set to the same, so I don't get why it's not working.

Thank you!

Comment: MyISAM or InnoDB? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2344118/utf-8-general-bin-unicode

Comment: InnoDB but I'm not sure, where can I find this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/213543/how-can-i-check-mysql-engine-type-for-a-specific-table

Comment: If you're using `utf8_swedish_ci`, why are you using `utf8` in the code?

Comment: `SHOW CREATE TABLE <TABLENAME>` - could you provide result of that?

Comment: Which version of MySQL? Not every version supports every character set..

Comment: According to what I see in their codebase, I would not recommend using it with anything, that has to do with money: https://github.com/litecart/litecart/blob/dev/public_html/includes/functions/func_password.inc.php#L28

Comment: @tereško I'm the author of LiteCart. What's wrong with password_hash()?

Comment: @tim in 2017 that codebase had no mention of `password_hash()`. And it looks like you switched to it only in [13 Aug 2019](https://github.com/litecart/litecart/commit/f6e8c5416c81826bb9ba2e200c4c282c8af770a2)  ... so ... this looks like somewhat disgusting attempt to spin a flaw that existed in 2017.

Answer (score 1):

Your quotes are messed up.  Let's see the entire line to help you figure it out.

Either of these works:

```
SET NAMES utf8;
SET NAMES 'utf8';
```

but the *real* problem is in what happens just before that (which we cannot see all of).

Also, when performing queries from *some* clients, the `;` should be left off.  Again, let's see the source code.

`utf8` (and `utf8mb4`) is a `CHARACTER SET`; that is what seems to be in question here.  Anything else (such as `utf8_unicode_520_ci`) is a `COLLATION`.